# Waypoints animation issue at 3d.io

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

The camera animation always starts from the initial camera pose.

We do not want this behaviour.

You can check this issue with: 
https://app.3d.io/default_setup.

This code worked before. We didn't change anything.

```html
<a-entity camera="" tour="autoStart: false" wasd-controls="" look-controls="" position="-2.073 1.6 -1.474" rotation="-2.063 203.308 0">
  <a-entity tour-waypoint="Top View" io3d-uuid="add7b140-7563-463a-b324-75e2b460e915" position="-7.959815433483447 22.172638840745442 1.675735956699384" rotation="-89.9 450 0"></a-entity>
  <a-entity tour-waypoint="Living" io3d-uuid="486a6760-e8d1-456d-a2d0-5358d65b2ef1" position="1.1168750348397785 1.037108274040117 1.7797448740972899" rotation="0 412.98472385428914 0"></a-entity>
  <a-entity tour-waypoint="Kitchen" io3d-uuid="4a0f17c1-fcde-4706-9188-48ddeb808927" position="-0.4316313757947364 1.37 0.10205065263211961" rotation="0 491.46180963572306 0"></a-entity>
  <a-entity tour-waypoint="Dining" io3d-uuid="5d76c74b-a2b5-4ddf-a6e9-a6fe009377b7" position="-1.0699430785395438 8 -3.5236261145326577" rotation="-38.48648648648648 539.873168157716 0"></a-entity>
  <a-entity tour-waypoint="Bedroom" io3d-uuid="4d6fec29-1467-40be-8f91-5435f0317072" position="-9.650512503727434 8 2.1338268605968826" rotation="-59.152761457109314 594.7591069330199 0"></a-entity>
  <a-entity tour-waypoint="Bedroom" io3d-uuid="3851ec4b-53c0-47d4-afc2-3d646043eb5d" position="-9.639031885443684 8 5.539305773258945" rotation="-56.77438307873098 400.8960173400832 0"></a-entity>
  <a-entity tour-waypoint="Master Bedroom" io3d-uuid="97eabbe1-578a-48ee-a40f-60af0187f2b1" position="-13.334875006116892 8 -1.701906768812833" rotation="-59.08108108108104 494.6322427235562 0"></a-entity>
  <a-entity tour-waypoint="Top View" io3d-uuid="fe33bb66-b1fe-4d13-9904-2e98fc05a525" position="-7.959815433483447 22.172638840745442 1.675735956699384" rotation="-89.9 450 0"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

This code doesn't work as desired either. The camera still kept same position.

```js
document.querySelector('[camera]').components['tour'].updateViewPoint({position:{y:1.6}, rotation:{x:0}})
```

Comment: The problem might be related to this: https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js/issues/115

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there was a somewhat breaking change in `aframe-animation-component` moving to version 4.x.x and if you find yourself using the following way of including that component:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
```

you wanna change it for this line:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@3.2.5/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tour animation will always tween from the current camera position to the next tour point.
So what you want to do is set your camera to the starting position either in aframe source code or programmatically:

```
<a-entity camera position="x y z"></a-entity>
```

Or via JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('[camera]').setAttribute('position', 'x y z');
```

Then you can set the next waypoint programmatically:

```
document.querySelector('[camera]').components['tour'].goTo(waypointUuid)
```

Or you can start the tour:

```
document.querySelector('[camera]').components['tour'].playTour()
```

If this does not work for you please describe your desired outcome and share your code with glitch or app creator.